# Possible to link an image in a playlist to a URL, with Flowplayer?

Tags: flash, flowplayer

I have a simple Flowplayer playlist. First one plays a short clip, which then cuts off, and an image is displayed. Is there a way to make the image clickable?

here is what I have:

```
<a  style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px" id="player"> </a>
<script>
    flowplayer("player", "../flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", { 
    playlist: [ 
        {url: 'http://e1h13.simplecdn.net/flowplayer/flowplayer.flv', duration: 10},
        {url: 'http://www.domain.com/image.jpg', duration: 100000}, 
    ], 
        plugins:  { 
        controls: null
    }           
    });
</script>
```

If there is another way of doing this, Im all ears. I need a video to play for 10 seconds (or entirely, since the file is gonna be 10 seconds long), and then display some text + a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using the content plugin and an onFinish callback on the first clip, like in this answer: [How to display HTML after video play finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547444/how-to-display-html-after-video-play-finishes/2550842#2550842)